# How to build node 5.4.0 npm 3.3.12 - earlier it was working fine

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Our application is in live that built with node 5.4.0 and npm 3.3.12. Till last week it was working fine. Now when we try to run command npm install I am getting npm error

```
38626 error node v5.4.0
38627 error npm  v3.3.12
38628 error code EMISSINGARG
38629 error typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
```

I see that I need to upgrade my project to latest npm. But that requires lot of time as my project is depending on webpack 1 version and old libraries. My question here is why it is stopped working. How can I fix this? I am attaching npm logs.

```
    38619 verbose headers   'content-encoding': 'gzip' }
38620 silly get cb [ 200,
38620 silly get   { date: 'Thu, 28 May 2020 09:46:20 GMT',
38620 silly get     'content-type': 'application/json',
38620 silly get     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
38620 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
38620 silly get     'set-cookie': [ '__cfduid=de470fd6ae02fefdbbaf3cbeada2f984c1590659179; expires=Sat, 27-Jun-20 09:46:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.npmjs.org; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax' ],
38620 silly get     'cf-ray': '59a70c3d493fc938-HYD',
38620 silly get     'cache-control': 'public, max-age=300',
38620 silly get     etag: 'W/"414ba14c1fef3e9df9d31821a3c138cf"',
38620 silly get     'last-modified': 'Sun, 26 Jan 2020 08:06:08 GMT',
38620 silly get     vary: 'accept-encoding, accept',
38620 silly get     'cf-cache-status': 'EXPIRED',
38620 silly get     'cf-request-id': '02fc45fa4f0000c9383abe1200000001',
38620 silly get     'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
38620 silly get     server: 'cloudflare',
38620 silly get     'content-encoding': 'gzip' } ]
38621 verbose get saving available-typed-arrays to /Users/thrinethrasiddani/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/available-typed-arrays/.cache.json
38622 verbose stack Error: Missing required argument #1
38622 verbose stack     at andLogAndFinish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most probably was older but you only discovered it last week/today. There is a [GitHub issue in npm repository](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/681) with people running on npm 3.5.2 complaining about the same thing. In short, it appears to be a npm bug or they have intentionally dropped support for older npm versions. The last comment in the thread suggests upgrading to latest npm 3.x, which is 3.10.10, which appears to still work.

As far as I'm aware, you only need to upgrade npm, not all the dependencies. However, I do suggest trying to keep your dependencies up to date to be compliant, have the latest security fixes and features.

If you wanna dig into it, [this](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v3.5.2/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js#L31) is where the error is thrown.

**Update:**
Somebody has found a fix which doesn't require npm/node upgrade: https://askubuntu.com/a/1098249/162155

Comment: Perfect. I can able to make build successful by upgrading npm to latest npm @3 version. Thanks @Silviu Burcea. Much appreciated.

Comment: i saw that post now. But it still uses new version but it is not working with npm version less thatn 3.10.0.